# Решить уравнение питон

Tags: python

как решить такое уравнение?    -0,235612354x - 2,9862145 - 4/sqrt(pi)*2^(x^3)=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip3 install sympy`

```
>>> from sympy import*
>>> x = Symbol('x')
>>> solve(-0.235612354*x - 2.9862145 - 4/sqrt(pi)*2**(x**3))
[]
```

Comment: странно у меня вроде анаконда но она ругается на этот код

Comment: Вместо запятых должны быть точки (в качестве разделителя целой и дробной части)

Comment: в анакоде открываю спайдер и он ругается на этот код

Comment: Не знаю, у меня нет анаконды.Sympy я поставил отдельно.

Comment: Черт все время путаю ` , . `

Comment: ```"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/solvers/solvers.py", line 1171, in solve
    solution = _solve(f[0], *symbols, **flags)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/solvers/solvers.py", line 1742, in _solve
    raise NotImplementedError('\n'.join([msg, not_impl_msg % f]))
NotImplementedError: multiple generators [x, 2**(x**3)]
No algorithms are implemented to solve equation -4*2**(x**3)/sqrt(pi) - 117806177*x/500000000 - 5972429/2000000```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58050582/solving-an-equation-containing-absolute-value-with-python-3